# Composing a message in Gnus runs Kmail

Tags: gnus

As a new Emacs user, I decided to start using Gnus. I achieved to configure it, but I didn't manage to send mail properly. Indeed, when I use either `C-c C-c` or `M-x message-send-and-exit`, it loads KMail (my default mail reader on Fedora 23 KDE) fulfilled with my mail specificities. Is there a way so I could send mail from Emacs itself?

=========================================================================

I fixed it using another emacs configuration on github (https://github.com/eschulte/emacs24-starter-kit/). I guess it's too soon for me to make my own configuration :)

Comment: Please move your edit, which provides an answer, to a real answer, which you can accept if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure emacs to use smtp. In my config file I have the
following.

```
(require 'smtpmail)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      starttls-use-gnutls t
      smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
      smtpmail-auth-credentials (expand-file-name "~/.authinfo.gpg")
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      smtpmail-debug-info t))
```

That should be everthing you need, hopefully.

I also have the following which you may need:

```
(setq gnus-posting-styles '(((header "to" "jtamagnan@gmail.com")
                 (address "jtamagnan@gmail.com"))))
```

Let me know if you find success!

Comment: Hi (I'm the one who posted), and thanks for helping! First, I think you should know I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org) which led to [this default configuration](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail).
So, I tried your solution, but I didn't do anything more : it still launch KMail... You know what it is? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a way of showing your actual config so that I try to help a bit more. Do you have a .authinfo or .authinfo.gpg file with your credentials? Thanks